# Change color of html lists and nested lists with CSS

Tags: html, css, list, nested, hover

I'm having troubles to find info that can solve my question.

I have an `<ul>` list with other lists nested inside it `<li>` child elements

I need to change the color of elements to blue when hover, except the last `<li>` element that needs to change color to orange when hover.

The problem is that I cannot change the color of the parents `<li>`, not sure if I'm explaining well.

The elements *Element1*, *Element2* must be blue when hover, and *Element3* must be orange when hover too.

It was my fault not to comment You cannot edit html (i.e. add a class attribute).

Thank you for your time!

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
  color: blue
}

ul li:last-child ul li:hover {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<html lang="en>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>List and lists colors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span href="">Element 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 1.1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 1.2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 1.3</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span href="">Element 2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 2.1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 2.2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 2.3</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span href="">Element 3</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 3.1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 3.2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span href="">Element 3.3</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the issue? the element sons of element 3 when hovered becomes orange

Comment: If you need to change colors to brown, type `brown`, not `blue`. And all Element 3.x changes to orange, so where's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry! @Michel I left brown by accident :(

Comment: Yes, elements 3.1, .2 and .3 are orange, but I need Element 3 be orange too when hover

Answer (score 0):

if you can't just assign them some classes, you could write

```
body > ul > li:last-child:hover {
    color:orange
}
```

..but actually the last li inside element 1 and 2 would change color too .. so i'd just add a few classes. like

```
<li class="element-1">
```

and then assign it some stile

```
.element-1:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with that. The goal was to not to edit the html code. It was my fault not to comment it

Comment: than maybe try **body > ul > li + li + li**